# Why does SQL Server return null-values for a given query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to create a table in SQL Server from an XML file. The XML file was downloaded at [https://iss.moex.com/iss/history/engines/stock/markets/bonds/boards/TQCB/securities/RU000A1032P1/.xml?from=2023-04-17&till=2023-04-21](https://stackoverflow.com)
It has the following structure:

```
<document>
    <data>
        <metadata>
            ...
        </metadata>
        <rows>
            <row TRADEDATE="2023-04-17" SHORTNAME="ВТБРКС01" SECID="RU000A1032P1" YIELDCLOSE = "12.93"  LEGALCLOSEPRICE="91.33" VOLUME="70824">
            <row ...>
            <row ...>
            ...
        </rows>
    </data>
```

After running the code in SQL it returns a table with NULL values in each cell.

I have tried the following code:

```
USE MoexTest
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM history

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT secid, shortname, legalcloseprice, yieldclose, volume
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'document/data/rows/row')
WITH 
(
secid [nvarchar](50) '@secid',
shortname [nvarchar] (10) '@shortname',
legalcloseprice [float] '@legalcloseprice',
yieldclose [float] '@yieldclose',
volume [integer] '@volume'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

So the result is:

| secid | shortname | legalcloseprice | yieldclose | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

But I was expecting:

| secid | shortname | legalcloseprice | yieldclose | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RU000A1032P1 | ВТБРКС01 | 91.33 | 12.93 | 70824 |
| RU000A1032P1 | ВТБРКС01 | 91.3 | 12.95 | 31166 |
| RU000A1032P1 | ВТБРКС01 | 91.23 | 13 | 15757 |
| RU000A1032P1 | ВТБРКС01 | 91.31 | 12.96 | 49363 |
| RU000A1032P1 | ВТБРКС01 | 91.5 | 12.86 | 22268 |

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would strongly recommend updating to XQuery, it was added to SQL Server as long as ago as SQL Server 2005 (perhaps even before then) and is much easier to work with (especially with sets of XML, such as when stored in a table).

The sample XML you've given isn't valid XML, the `row` node with data wasn't closed, and `document` had no end node for example, so I've had to "fix" that manually. Hopefully the XML you have is actually valid as otherwise this *won't* work (if it isn't, then focusing on getting the XML valid is important).

Once you have valid XML then the query looks like this:

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<document>
    <data>
        <metadata>
        </metadata>
        <rows>
            <row TRADEDATE="2023-04-17" SHORTNAME="ВТБРКС01" SECID="RU000A1032P1" YIELDCLOSE = "12.93"  LEGALCLOSEPRICE="91.33" VOLUME="70824" />
            <row/>
            <row/>
        </rows>
    </data>
</document>'; 

SELECT r.r.value('@TRADEDATE','date') AS TRADEDATE,
       r.r.value('@SHORTNAME','nvarchar(15)') AS SHORTNAME,
       r.r.value('@SECID','varchar(30)') AS SECID,
       r.r.value('@YIELDCLOSE','decimal(12,2)') AS YIELDCLOSE,
       r.r.value('@LEGALCLOSEPRICE','decimal(12,2)') AS LEGALCLOSEPRICE,
       r.r.value('@VOLUME','int') AS VOLUME
FROM @xml.nodes('document/data/rows/row')r(r);
```

Note that the data types are *guessed*, so you may need to adjust them for your actual data.

Comment: That works. Thanks! However, I can't find out how to update to XQuery.

Comment: By "update" I mean update *your* practices, @konstantintre . There's no reason to be using the "ancient" `sp_xml_preparedocument` and related procedures along side `OPENXML` when XQuery has been available for *at least* *18 years*.

Comment: I get it. I'm a self-learner and found this solution somewhere in the Internet. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Thom_A, I have one more question for you if you don't mind. Is there a way to use a link to the xml file stored on drive instead of putting the 'document' into the body of the query?

Comment: You could use `OPENROWSET` or something, but that's a *different* question, @konstantintre .

Comment: @konstantintre Probably best to use something like Powershell to read the file and pass it through as a parameter to `Invoke-DbaQuery` or `SqlCommand`

Comment: @Charlieface I'm afraid it's too complicated for me. But I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Not really, it's just two lines `$data = Get-Content "Somepath.xml" -Raw; Invoke-DbaQuery -Query "insert ..." -SqlParameter @{Name = "@xmlParam"; Value = $xml } ...` https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work when attributes with matching case are used. Make your attribute selectors UPPERCASE to match the data:

```
SELECT secid, shortname, legalcloseprice, yieldclose, volume
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'document/data/rows/row')
WITH 
(
secid [nvarchar](50) '@SECID',
shortname [nvarchar] (10) '@SHORTNAME',
legalcloseprice [float] '@LEGALCLOSEPRICE',
yieldclose [float] '@YIELDCLOSE',
volume [integer] '@VOLUME'
)
```

Comment: `OPENXML` is a *really* old way of doing this; why not "update" to Xquery? It was added to SQL server in *2005*.

Comment: Yep I totally agree.